# How to grep on mysql CLI command output?

Tags: linux, command-line, mysql, grep

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for source to send event
                  Master_Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000010
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 95732736
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000005
                Relay_Log_Pos: 12260050
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000010
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

I want to perform grep on the output of the above mysql CLI command.

Something like

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G | grep Slave_*
```

Can it be done? If not is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command like:

```
mysql -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS;'|grep Slave_
```

`-e` from execute

If you need username/password command become:

```
  mysql -u<user> -p -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS;'|grep Slave_
```

Comment: I've to specify `-uroot -p` as well as it needs access, anything to run on `mysql>` command to achieve the same result?

Comment: @Vaughn, on the same you you do in command!!! See my edited answer